# "ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 kills url paths

Tags: c#, url, odata

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

I added this line to my web.config file in order to use OData but now my css, js, image files does not load. If I remove this line there is no problem. Is there a work around on this?

Comment: What were you trying to accomplish by adding that line?

Comment: It lets me to use "." in url. It was in http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/odata-actions-and-functions

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around. Usually when we want to call custom actions we should do something like this:

```
url/Users/Namespace.CustomAction
```

However if we add this configuration

```
config.EnableUnqualifiedNameCall(unqualifiedNameCall: true);
```

in WebApiConfig file the we can use actions and functions without need for namespaces.

```
url/Users/CustomAction
```

Like this.

Comment: Yes. That's a workaround. [Here](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#06-01-custom-url-parsing) is a simple sample page for Uri parser enhancement.